# Images Storing and retrieving In magnolia?

Tags: magnolia

I have uploaded images in resources module and used in htmlcomponent.
Which is working fine.

I have cleared the temp ,work folders and restarted the tomcat instances.

After restart I am not able to see images in HTML component.When I try to open the images, it's saying sub-app failed to start : binary

I can see in logs we have null pointer exception.

> 2015-06-26 13:14:28,810 ERROR agnolia.ui.framework.app.AppInstanceControllerImpl: Sub-app binary failed to start: null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.integration.jcr.AbstractJcrNodeAdapter.getItemProperty(AbstractJcrNodeAdapter.java:170)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.integration.jcr.JcrNodeAdapter.getItemProperty(JcrNodeAdapter.java:104)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.item.FileTransformer.createPropertyFromItem(FileTransformer.java:173)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.item.FileTransformer.readFromItem(FileTransformer.java:130)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.item.FileTransformer.readFromItem(FileTransformer.java:77)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.TransformedProperty.(TransformedProperty.java:59)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.factory.AbstractFieldFactory.initializeProperty(AbstractFieldFactory.java:238)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.factory.AbstractFieldFactory.createField(AbstractFieldFactory.java:114)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormBuilder.buildReducedForm(FormBuilder.java:214)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormBuilder.buildForm(FormBuilder.java:122)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.DetailPresenter.setItemView(DetailPresenter.java:159)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.DetailPresenter.start(DetailPresenter.java:138)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.DetailEditorPresenter.start(DetailEditorPresenter.java:122)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.DetailEditorPresenter.start(DetailEditorPresenter.java:101)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.DetailSubApp.start(DetailSubApp.java:118)
>           at info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.DetailSubApp.start(DetailSubApp.java:71)

Is the binary files will be stored in temp ? what happen with the every release?

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Should not be related to temp. Most likely it is incorrectly set type. Should be binary/image. Compare it with other images that are working. I'm on my phone only now so can't verify. If you can't open even images that are in resources by default then something is wrong with the co fig of resources app.